# how we can attach Ajax model popup with a Data grid default edit button

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-ajax

I have a made panel with ajax modal popup which opens on a simple button.But i want to open popup with data grid default edit button or select button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this `ModalPopup Demonstration`,  http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/ajax-control-toolkit/modalpopup/launching-a-modal-popup-window-from-server-code-cs

You will have a better understanding how the modal popup works.